# StepSize in Rating Bar Android

Tags: android, ratingbar

```
   <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.1"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    android:rating="3.1"
    />
```

If I give rating from 3.1 to 3.5,then rating showing is 3.5 only.

I need rating to be set in exact value(e.g: 3.1).

StepSize is also set to 0.1.

Please anyone help me in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

> TRY LIKE THIS

```
  <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    />


    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {

            if(rating == 1.0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "3.1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(rating == 2.0)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "3.2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't use statically became I will get **Rating Data** from Server.

Comment: It may vary from 0.1 to 5

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113807/when-i-use-custom-stars-for-android-ratingbar-always-show-half-star-for-decimal *use this you get right ans*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatRatingBar
            android:id="@+id/rb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:isIndicator="false"
            android:numStars="6"
            android:stepSize=".1"
            app:secondaryProgressTint="#00000000"
            android:numStars="6"
           />
```

If you set `secondaryProgressTint` in `RatingBar`, it will work with versions **>= 21**. To support all versions use `AppCompatRatingBar`

Answer (score -1):

Try to adjust your ratingBar with the property android:width="match_parent" 
 in your parent layout, this will take your step size in mind and behave with decimal rating.

you can better get it [Here](https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar).