# Rating bar with style fills the stars half or fully when giving any rating value

Tags: android, android-activity, floating-point, ratingbar

I'am working on small sized golden yellow color ratingbar,which is to show some rating in float numbers like 4.2,3.75 etc.I have implemented the rating bar as below:-

```
                    <RatingBar
                        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
                        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:isIndicator="true"
                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
                        android:progressTint="@color/golden_yellow"
                        android:secondaryProgressTint="@color/golden_yellow"
                     />
```

@style/RatingBar:-

```
     <style name="RatingBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/golden_yellow</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/golden_yellow</item>
    <item name="ratingBarStyle">@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small</item>
</style>
```

Now the problem is ,stars of rating bar is fully or half filled when giving the rating value as like 4.2 or 4.7 etc.I have given the stepsize as 0.1

```
    ratingBar1.setStepSize((float) 0.1);

    ratingBar1.setRating((float) 4);
```

I have given rating value as 4.2 but getting the output like this:

[image]

can someone help me to find the answer????

Comment: It would be useful if if you post the screenshots.

Comment: I have posted the screenshot.please check the question

Comment: Check this and you have create custom rating bar.
[Custom rating bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113807/when-i-use-custom-stars-for-android-ratingbar-always-show-half-star-for-decimal)

Comment: Sorry it does'nt worked for me.atlast i have used a library 
   https://github.com/FlyingPumba/SimpleRatingBar